# How to make a custom boot-up splash animation

Tags: 11.04, customization, plymouth

I just found some cool boot-up video and audio file, and I want to make a custom boot-up animation in Ubuntu 11.04. Any suggestions?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo

Answer (score 3):

The startup splash is displayed by Plymouth in Ubuntu. There is an [extensive documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Documentation/Plymouth) on Plymouth scripting and creating custom plymouth themes in Ubuntu wiki.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Plymouth splash in 11.10:

1. Open *Accessories* > *Terminal*
2. Run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install plymouth-manager`
5. Open in applications menu.