# How do I debrand the boot splash screen?

Tags: plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make a custom boot up splash animation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60606/how-to-make-a-custom-boot-up-splash-animation)

When I boot up my computer it displays a splash animation: the word "Ubuntu" with dots underneath indicating that the system is loading. I'd like to remove the word "Ubuntu" and keep the dots. I **don't** want to [disable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen) or [remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot) the splash screen.

I like Ubuntu - I even like Unity :D - I'd just prefer a debranded look.

Is this possible? Answers applicable to both 11.04 and 11.10 preferred.