# How can I customize the Ubuntu boot up logo?

Tags: customization, plymouth, custom-distributions, logo

I am making a custom distribution, and have a question about the Ubuntu Logo with 5 dots displayed when booting up.

The `Ubuntu-Logo-Script` in the `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntutext` folder has the word Ubuntu and beneath that 5 progressing 'dots'. Is it possible to remove the progress bar dots, and instead replace it with a faded Ubuntu logo, that gradually colors up to full?

[image]

Answer (score 142, accepted):

### Install Theme

I have created theme as you wanted with a faded Ubuntu logo (moreover I have added an animation of the Ubuntu logo. Hope you'd like it :-P )

**Screenshot**

[image: Spinning Ubuntu logo and the Ubuntu text logo with a moving fade effect.]

**Want to see it live?**

Go to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPo50gM3txU

**Where can you get this theme?**

I have uploaded it to Mediafire cloud [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?ctxpjhnkx5k9kyk).

**How do you install it?**

Download from the above link, save it on your Desktop, then issue these commands one by one.
Please replace `/lib/plymouth/themes` with `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` in the commands, if you are on 16.04 or later.

```
cd ~/Desktop/
tar -xf ubuntufaded.tar
sudo cp -r ubuntu-faded-screen '/lib/plymouth/themes'
sudo rm '/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth'
sudo ln -s '/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-faded-screen/ubuntu-faded-screen.plymouth' '/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth'
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**How to check it?**

1. Restart Ubuntu and you'll see a nice animation while booting up and
   shutting down. OR
2. Copy the whole command below and paste it into a terminal and hit enter. (You will probably need to install a package: `sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11`)

   `sudo plymouthd --debug --debug-file=/tmp/plymouth-debug-out ; sudo  plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0;I<10;I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo  plymouth --update=event$I ; done ; sudo  plymouth --quit`

### How to create a Plymouth theme yourself

Plymouth Scripting Language is very similar to C or JavaScript. If you know these languages, it'll be very easy to create Plymouth scripts yourself.

Let's start with basics like operators, looping, comments, etc. Three type of comments are supported.

```
# comment like in bash
// single line comment like in C
/* block comments */
```

Statements are terminated with a semicolon, e.g.

```
foo = 10;
```

Statement blocks can be created with curly brackets, e.g.

```
{
    foo = 10;
    z = foo + foo;
}
```

The supported operators are `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`. 
Shorthand assignment operators are also supported `+=, -=, *=,` etc. 
Unary operators are also supported, e.g.

```
foo *= ++z;
```

`+` is used for concatenation e.g.

```
foo = "Jun" + 7; # here foo is "Jun7"
```

Comparison operator example:

```
x = (3 >= 1); # assign 1 to x because it's true
y = ("foo" == "bar"); # assign 0 to y because it's false
```

Conditional operations and looping:

```
if (foo > 4)
{
    foo--;
    z = 1;
}
else
    z = 0;


while (foo--)
    z *= foo;
```

`&&`, `||`, `!` are also supported.

```
if ( foo > 0 && foo <4 )
```

This may be new to many readers: hashes, similar to arrays. Hashes can be created by accessing their contents using `dot` or `[ ]` brackets, e.g.

```
foo.a = 5;
x = foo["a"] ; # x equals to 5
```

Use the `fun` keyword to define function, e.g.

```
fun animator (param1, param2, param3)
{
    if (param1 == param2)
        return param2;
    else
        return param3;
}
```

### The two basic Plymouth objects

#### Image

To create a new Image, give the filename of an image within the theme directory to `Image()`. Remember, *only .png files are supported*. For example:

```
background = Image ("black.png");
```

To show a text message you must create an `Image` of the text. (This might surprise you.) For example:

```
text_message_image = Image.Text("I love Ubuntu");
```

Width and height can be found using `GetWidth()` and `GetHeight()`; for example:

```
image_area = background.GetWidth() * background.GetHeight();
```

One can rotate or change the size of an Image; for example:

```
down_image = logo_image.Rotate (3.1415); # Image can be Rotated. Parameter to Rotate is the angle in radians
fat_image = background.Scale ( background.GetWidth() * 4 , background.GetHeight () ) # make the image four times the width
```

#### Sprite

Use `Sprite` to place an `Image` on screen.

Creating a `Sprite`:

```
first_sprite = Sprite ();
first_sprite.SetImage (background);
```

Or by supplying image to its constructor,

```
first_sprite = Sprite (background);
```

How to set different the sprite to different positions on screen (x,y,z):

```
first_sprite.SetX (300); # put at x=300
first_sprite.SetY (200); # put at y=200
background.SetZ(-20);
foreground.SetZ(50);
```

Or you can set all at once with `SetPosition()`:

```
first_sprite.Setposition(300, 200, 50) # put at x=300, y=200, z=50
```

Changing opacity:

```
faded_sprite.SetOpacity (0.3);
invisible_sprite.SetOpacity (0);
```

Some miscellaneous methods used are:

```
Window.GetWidth();
Window.GetHeight();
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.5, 0, 0); # RGB values between 0 to 1.
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.4, 0.3, 0.6);
Plymouth.GetMode(); #  returns a string of one of: "boot", "shutdown", "suspend", "resume" or unknown.
etc.
```

#### Predefined Functions

```
Plymouth.SetRefreshFunction (function); # Calling Plymouth.SetRefreshFunction with a function will set that function to be called up to 50 times every second
Plymouth.SetBootProgressFunction(); # function is called with two numbers, time spent booting so far and the progress (between 0 and 1)
Plymouth.SetRootMountedFunction(); # function is called when a new root is mounted
Plymouth.SetKeyboardInputFunction(); # function is called with a string containing a new character entered on the keyboard
Plymouth.SetUpdateStatusFunction(); # function is called with the new boot status string
Plymouth.SetDisplayPasswordFunction(); # function is called when the display should display a password dialogue. First param is prompt string, the second is the number of bullets.
Plymouth.SetDisplayQuestionFunction(); # function is called when the display should display a question dialogue. First param is prompt string, the second is the entry contents.
Plymouth.SetDisplayNormalFunction(); # function is called when the display should return to normal
Plymouth.SetMessageFunction(); # function is called when new message should be displayed. First arg is message to display.
```

#### Mathematical Functions

```
Math.Abs()
Math.Min()
Math.Pi()
Math.Cos()
Math.Random()
Math.Int()
etc.
```

#### It is better to modify an existing script than to start from scratch.

Open up `.script` file from my uploaded theme and try to understand what it does. A fantastic guide can be found  [here](http://brej.org/blog/?cat=16).

I'm sure you'll learn this. It isn't hard. Let me know if you need any help.

*Hope it'd help you create one yourself.*

**Answer to Roshan George's Comment** : 
`Is it possible to replace the purple colour with an image as background in the default Plymouth theme names "ubuntu-logo" ?`

```
background = Image ("your-image.png"); 
sprite = Sprite (background.Scale (Window.GetWidth(), Window.GetHeight()));
sprite.SetX (0); # put at x=0
sprite.SetY (0); # put at y=0
```

You might need to add `sprite.SetZ (-10);`

You should remove

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (p, q, r);
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (a, b, c);
```

where `p, q, r, a, b, c` are some values.

More links

- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/
- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/Scripts/
- https://www.khattam.info/plymouth-preview-a-tool-to-preview-your-plymouth-theme-2010-11-19.html
- http://brej.org/blog/?p=158

Comment: Can i get the same as u have created but with the ubuntu logo and text(in same positions like now) glowing and diming alternately(when logo glows,txt dims and when text glows,logo dims) with no rotating border and a slit progress as the Ubuntu9.10 playmouth...i.e this-https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Incoming/Karmic/Boot/Demo?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=xsplash-3.png....I would like to have only the slit progress bar like the one in the link...the txt and logo being in positions same as urs...Can u help me have that?? m trying to learn from what u have xplained meanwhile...Thanx! gr8 answer

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could upvote more than 1 time :D

Comment: @Rinzwind : I just gave him "10 upvotes" on behalf of us all :)

Comment: Thanks man, the tutorial is superb. I look forwrd in diting this. Is that allowed ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge sure, you can edit this. We have power of Freedom ! :-)

Comment: I would like to know whether it is possible to change the live cd plymouth theme ?

Comment: You have to [create your own LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).

Comment: @virpara You have created a full *Plymouth Scripting Language* guide! You can create Wikipedia entry with that info :)

Comment: Is it possible to replace the purple colour with an image as bavkground in the default plymouth theme names "ubuntu-logo" ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge I've updated the answer.

Comment: @virpara , but this doesnot show up in an distro made using ubuntu-builder. What privileges should be given ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge Did you run `sudo ln -s '/lib/plymouth/themes/your-theme/your-script.plymouth' '/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth';
sudo update-initramfs -u` ? this command changes your default plymouth theme and updates initrd file

Comment: i did that, but still it is not showing..i just get a black screen. should i do chmod a+x to the themes folder ?

Comment: @RoshanGeorge Are you able to check that using `plymouth-x11` ?

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: please follow `How to check it ?` in answer.

Comment: Hi, I found the initrd file and it has the plymouth theme I made, but it is not running when I either boot up the live cd, or when I instal it.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge Did you put that `initrd` file in your `squashfs` and also inside `iso` file ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu-builder, so uncompressing and compressing of squashfs is done automatically, so, s there a provision for adding it?

Comment: You have to do it using `chroot`. You should not put your `/boot/initrd` to extracted file-system(from `.squashfs`). Please wait for a day or two. I'll put complete guide here.

Comment: @viapara unbelievable tutorial really appreciate the level of detail! I have customized your original file a little bit and I have one question I am running this on ubuntu 15.10 and when it starts up the background is black even though I have set the background top and bottom to white. The only colors that are white are the images that I have replaced yours with? Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Note that in 16.04, the themes directory location changed to: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`

Comment: Holy crap, this is impressive. A well deserved +1.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 16.04, the plymouth theme directory has been changed as told by another comment. Please update your answer to reflect this, if you have a chance. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for posting such a helpful answer. Once I had tried to modify a Plymouth script, but I became mad by looking at a long script. But after reading your answer, I can now make a complete meaning out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Plymouth Manager to change this. You can get it from [from here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/plymouth-manager/+download) or run the commands below.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/plymouth-manager/trunk/stable/+download/plymouth-manager_1.5.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i plymouth-manager_1.5.0-1_all.deb
```

After that you will need to launch `plymouth-manager` with the command:

```
sudo plymouth-manager
```

The "magic" command if you want to do all by yourself, (writing your own plymouth config file), and you want to apply it when you are ready is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the GRUB screen with the GRUB Customizer software. But if you want to change the Plymouth screen it's different.

All the things of this software is in the `/lib/plymouth/themes` directory and **all the animation** of this one is in the `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script` file.

If you want to modify to your liking Plymouth, all you need is on the `ubuntu-logo` folder.

You can do it by your own without the help of any external software, but *you must understand programming*.

Also you can find tools to do that in the Ubuntu repository, but you need to learn to create Plymouth themes.

Good luck!