# How to change background color of the dots during boot

Tags: 13.04, plymouth

I am fine with Ubuntu splash screen and I don't want another theme, I just want to change the background color to black, the five white dots to black, and the five orange dots which overlap the original white dots to black. How can I do that?

Comment: "I don't want another theme" and " I just want to change " means you want another theme :) So: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo

Comment: Well I guess you are right, but I really don't want another logo or sprites or image, just want to change the color of default plymouth theme, not getting another themes or create a new one.

Comment: Replace the dot images in /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo with a new one.

Comment: @nur I would favor making a new theme and change that theme ;) safety 1st.