# Disk errors while trying to boot LiveUSB on laptop

Tags: boot, live-usb, laptop, systemd

I made an Ubuntu 15.04 LiveUSB and now am trying to boot it to install on a SSD. While trying to boot from it the following errors happen:

```
[    7.027548] ACPI PCC probe failed.
starting version 219
error opening USB device 'descriptors' file
[    9.867586] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    9.867609] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  360.016989] INFO: task kworker/u16:2:59 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.017064]       Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[  360.017080] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  360.017153] INFO: task systemd-udevd:126 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.017173]       Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[  360.017188] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  360.017254] INFO: task systemd-udevd:127 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.017273]       Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[  360.017289] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  360.017365] INFO: task systemd-udevd:128 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360.017384]       Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[  360.017399] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
worker [130] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda is taking a long time
worker [133] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sr0 is taking a long time
timeout 'ata_id --export /dev/sda'
slow: 'ata_id --export /dev/sda' [143]
worker [130] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda timeout; kill it
seq 1188 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda' killed
worker [133] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sr0 timeout; kill it
seq 1198 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sr0' killed
worker [130] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
worker [126] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 is taking a long time
worker [127] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 is taking a long time
worker [128] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3 is taking a long time
worker [126] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 timeout; kill it
seq 1189 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda' killed
worker [127] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 timeout; kill it
seq 1190 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sr0' killed
worker [128] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3 timeout; kill it
seq 1191 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3' killed
```

A couple of hours staring in front of the screen, I just shutdown the machine because there is nothing I can do.

FYI, the worker lines sometimes doesn't appear, so the INFO statements display the actual error.

Some concerns:

- The USB was built using Startup Disk Creator from Ubuntu 14.10
- The ISO is *not* corrupt according to sha256sum
- Yeah, I wrote down 'da whole text manually
- Couldn't find any real dupe, [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/622348/62483) (and child posts too) doesn't contain any solution. Even I tried adding `nomodeset` to the grunt file but no luck at all
- The USB stick is 2.0, but I tried with both ports 2.0 and 3.0
- Just tried the USB stick on another computer and is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/341241/62483) has some interesting stuff. Braiam said that there could be an electrical issue related. In fact, I turn off the machine, wait 'till the next day, unplug the electrical power and it's working! Damn electrical power..

Answer (score 0):

Try using UnetBootin, and also, make sure you are using a USB 2.0. USB 3.0 is backwards compatible inside OS, but not always for booting to USB, I think your BIOS needs USB 3.0 Drivers for that to work.

Comment: The USB stick is fine and using other ports I got the same results.