# Can a GIF be used as the Ubuntu Splash Screen instead of the boring purple one?

Tags: plymouth

I'm using Ubuntu Builder and I really want to change the splash screen. It's my first time using Ubuntu Builder, and most of the work is being done offline (limited access...). By following the instructions in [this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173329/what-alternatives-are-available-to-replace-the-purple-boot-splash-screen) I've managed to [set a custom plymouth background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/a/179166/212123). It is just a still image.

But I was just curious to know if I could use an animated GIF image for the splash-screen replacing the need for the codes in plymouth script to swap through `.png` images for boot animation.

Comment: I don't know why this Q is being voted for a close?! It's about tweaking Ubuntu! I'm voting to leave it open..

Comment: @rusty can you illustrate us what is the problem? I only see "how to add a gif to the boot screen" but I don't see what's the problem OP is facing with the guide he's following.

Comment: @Braiam "how to add a gif to the boot screen" is the actual Q here as far as I understand (but yeah I don't know why OP had to include the script)...

Comment: @Braiam what do you reckon, not worth a reopen?

Comment: @rusty no, it's still unclear, I have no idea how can this be answered if OP doesn't clarify the question.

Comment: mind you: there are 2 links in the body but those do not help me to understand this either

Comment: @rusty it's unclear as we don't know exactly what OP problem is. That's as far as it goes. 2) Once OP edit his question it's put in the reopen queue, *we don't need to wait* for OP to fix their Q to close it. We close it because it can't be answered.

Comment: Why is the answer in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  You can't.  Animated gifs are unsupported by plymouth at this time.

You have to use timers and swap the image yourself.

Comment: I know this isn't stated int he question but how would you create something similar to a gif, with pictures and timers. A step by step guide would be helpful :).

Comment: It exists already... Google finds it.

Comment: it would be great if you could include it here too..

Comment: Google links are fragile they can disappear at any time....

Comment: There's also an example already on site here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo

Comment: FWIW: I'm making an app to do this.

Comment: Thanks @hbdgaf, your post on March 11th helped substantially.