# Create Startup Screen

Tags: 15.04, startup, startupmanager

Is it possible to make my own screen instead of having those 5 orange/white dots. I want to make it on my 15.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: It's possible though a lot of work and [this should help you get started](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screen is called the Plymouth splash screen. There are several themes for Plymouth that you can install and use. You can do your own theme, too. Take a look at the following link for more details.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth