# How to remove Xubuntu load/shutdown screen

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments

I installed XFCE and then uninstalled it because I didn't like it anymore. I expected the loadscreen to get removed (crazy right?) but it's stuck there. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are hoping to completely uninstall Xubuntu and go back to pure Ubuntu, I have found that this command works for me (tested on Ubuntu 15.04):

(It's a long one but here you go:)

```
sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview alacarte bison blueman brltty-x11 catfish espeak exo-utils flex fonts-droid fonts-lyx gigolo gmusicbrowser gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs gthumb gthumb-data gtk2-engines-pixbuf indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-sound-gtk2 leafpad  libbison-dev libdigest-crc-perl libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libfl-dev libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgstreamer-perl libgtk2-notify-perl libgtk2-trayicon-perl libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkspell0 libido-0.1-0 libindicate-gtk3 libintl-perl libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libkeybinder0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libnet-dbus-perl liboobs-1-5 libots0 librarian0 libsexy2 libtagc0 libthunarx-2-0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtumbler-1-0 libunique-1.0-0 libvte-common libvte9 libwv-1.2-4 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-utils libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl lightdm-gtk-greeter link-grammar-dictionaries-en m4 orage parole pastebinit pavucontrol pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog pidgin-otr plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-xubuntu-text python-configobj rarian-compat ristretto screensaver-default-images scrollkeeper shimmer-themes system-tools-backends tcl8.5 thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman ttf-droid tumbler tumbler-common xbrlapi xchat xchat-common xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-appfinder xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-notifyd xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-terminal xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf xfdesktop4 xfdesktop4-data xfwm4 xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl xubuntu-artwork xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I believe that the specific command in the list that removes the XFCE logo screen is:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo
```

Although this will onyl remove the XFCE screen and not re-install the Ubuntu one, as that would require the command below to be used:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

That will re-install the standard ubuntu desktop items such as the logo screens

Alternativly, you could try to install a custom logo screen similar to this: [Custom Logo Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo)

Let me know how this works for you,

T3CHI5

Comment: That was quick! Yeah thanks, this led me to exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to help! If there is anything else you need just let me know :)

Comment: Well while you're here, how do I change the look of the login screen? Mine is stuck on GNOME.

Comment: I have found that the "Sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" command installs the default ubuntu logo screen for me. Hence, I have not customised mine personally - although I do know that the logo files are stored in "/lib/plymouth/themes" and there is a detailed description of how to add a custom logo screen here: "http://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo"

Comment: Well thanks again. Never have I had so much fun booting and rebooting my device. :P

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. This solved it for me. Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

If asked to, select the non-xubuntu option by choosing the appropriate number in the menu (in my case it was `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth`), and finish by running this on the terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the updated answer!