# Custom animated boot up splash screen (whole screen)

Tags: boot, display-resolution, customization, plymouth, logo

so I was going off of this thread: [How can I customize the Ubuntu boot up logo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo) and I run it, and it works great. However, I only want to animate one thing, and for it to take up the whole screen. I made a .png that was the same resolution as my screen. I tested it as a background and it looked crisp and took over the whole screen. However, I would like to have multiple .pngs (same resolution) to play as an animation. I tried doing it with the code from the previous thread. I replaced the ubuntu1-30.pngs with my own. However, my logo does not appear and the splash screen starts off the same with the exception of my pngs. This is the part I have edited. I really only changed the resolution of my png, and the location of it. I put it to x=0, y=0 since that's when the wallpaper looked the best. I even tried changing z=1000 so it wouldn't be in the background. Not sure why my methods aren't working. Any ideas?

```
#Window.SetBackgroundTopColor(255, 255, 255);
#Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor(255, 255, 255);

#---------- Ubuntu faded start--------
indexnum = 1;
while (1){
    frame_image[indexnum] = ImageNew("ubuntu"+ indexnum +".PNG");
    if (!frame_image[indexnum]) break;
    indexnum++;
}
frame_count = indexnum + 1;
frame_index = 1;
ubuntu_sprite = SpriteNew();


#----------- Refresh function ----------

fun refresh_callback (){
    if (status == "normal"){
        motif.sprite.SetOpacity(motif.opacity);

        frame_index += 20 / 50;
        frame_index %= frame_count;
        int_frame_index = MathInt(frame_index);
        SpriteSetImage (ubuntu_sprite, frame_image[int_frame_index]);
        ubuntu_sprite.SetX(0);
        ubuntu_sprite.SetY(0);
        #SpriteSetX (ubuntu_sprite, SpriteWindowGetWidth()  / 2 - ImageGetWidth(frame_image[int_frame_index])  / 2);
        #SpriteSetY (ubuntu_sprite, SpriteWindowGetHeight() / 4 + ImageGetWidth( RotatedImage1(0) ) );
    }
    else{
        SpriteSetOpacity (ubuntu_sprite, 0);
    }
}
```