# What are the minimum requirements to program a Display manager?

Tags: login, python3, display-manager

I want to program a display manager or my own login program.
So that Ubuntu boots up and then comes for example a program that says hello(instead of a Display Manager) and that after the program is finished I am logged in?
Where do I put the executable file(I want to write the code with Python)?
Is there a way without plymouth?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I customize the Ubuntu boot up logo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo)

Comment: The prior possible-duplicates do meet your requirements I suspect; if used with auto-login.  The DM also generally handles user login, so if you plan on doing this too (ie. check the user account & password is valid, then & only then continue) changing `plymouth` won't be enough, but it does read like you don't want this.

Comment: Can't I skip authentication?

Comment: If you have auto-login enabled - then the prior 'possible duplicate' links are exactly what you want - ie. just a plymouth screen, any DM you want & auto-login.  The primary reason against plymouth, is you want the coding experience, (why you mentioned python), where I don't know if you can use python in creating a plymouth screen.

Comment: Is there also a way without plymouth and with Python?