# How to set a custom splash screen on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, themes, customization, plymouth

I recently wanted to make a custom splash screen on Ubuntu. I don't want to use some pre-built splash screen. Instead, I want to use my own GIF/PNG/MP4 file to set as splash screen.

Is it possible? If yes, then how could I do it?

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-boot-splash-screen-logo-linux/

Comment: @24601 sorry but this method does not work for me - I have no directory /lib/plymouth... Is there a file where I can set the splash_screen="/path/to/file.png"?..

Comment: odd.. I'm using v20.04 and in terminal typing `cd /usr/share/plymouth/themes` takes me straight to it. What did you type?

Comment: @24601 I typed `cd /lib/plymouth/themes` because the guide on makeuseof said so, but I have no directory **/lib/plymouth**... Could you maybe make a new guide here on how to do it?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the Ubuntu boot up logo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143330/how-can-i-customize-the-ubuntu-boot-up-logo)  Note that in recent versions, the themes directory location has been changed to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` instead of `/lib/plymouth/themes`

Comment: @MrMoon The guide that [24601 posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356558/ubuntu-20-04-custom-splash-screen?noredirect=1#comment2322456_1356558) should still be valid. It specifically mentions: *"More recent versions of Ubuntu had the location as `/lib/plymouth/themes`. As of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, that location has been moved, to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`. "* So just replace `/lib/plymouth/themes` with `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` in the commands given.