# How to replace the Ubuntu 20.04 logo globally?

Tags: 20.04, customization, custom-distributions, logo

Is there a way of replacing the Ubuntu logo globally? I want to replace the logo on boot time, on login page and in Settings → *About* (the orange logo).

Thanks in advance. If you want me to specify a bit more, please ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP already asked it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356558/ubuntu-20-04-custom-splash-screen?noredirect=1#comment2322687_1356558)

Comment: @24601 Sorry, but it's a different question - here I am asking how to replace the LOGO and here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356558/ubuntu-20-04-custom-splash-screen?noredirect=1#comment2322687_1356558 I am asking how to change splash screen...

Answer (score 2):

The icon file is named `distributor-logo.svg`. To find it, use:

```
locate distributor-logo.svg
```

In Ubuntu 20.04, I found it in the following locations (there are also some icons in the `/snap` directory which I have not listed here).

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/16/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/22/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/24/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/48/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/64/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/16/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/22/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/24/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/48/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/places/64/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/16/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/22/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/16/distributor-logo.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/22/distributor-logo.svg
```

You can take a backup of these files and replace these with your favorite logo of appropriate size to change the Ubuntu logo system-wide.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the Ubuntu orange logo but I also wanted to replace the Ubuntu logo which says "ubuntu" - what should I do? Could you please tell me about it?

Comment: @MrMoon I don't know that